# Laravel Unresponsive Via Http Request (PHPUnit Works Ok)

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx

I'm developing a Laravel App using Docker.  Using nginx:1.12 and php:7.2-fpm images.

Today I've added the tymon/jwt-auth package, and via TDD got it working.  The trouble now is that all http requests (through the web browser, or Postman) are unresponsive.  The request loads endlessly (10 minutes and counting now...) and throws no errors.

As hinted above, all tests are working fine and are all green.  So via PHPUnit the app works fine.  Just not via a http request.

Does anyone know how I can go about diagnosing this?

I've attempted to put at dd("here") at the very start of the app in the bootstrap/app.php file to work forwards but it doesn't appear to even get that far as this die and dump doesn't show.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide us some logs?

Comment: as you described, I think the problem is misconfiguration of nginx.
please provide your nginx config and your dockerfile.

Comment: Likely a problem with your webserver (nginx) but you should receive time-out error. Can you ping it successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm unsure how it fixed itself.  I have just come back home and my laptop needed rebooting.  Now it is working.

I had tried restarting before...